# React Redux : Why dispatching causing my local component states to reset

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm currently working on a ReactTS Project (v18.2) using Redux Toolkit (v.1.9.7) to handle my store

I don't understand why when I dispatch something into my store, **local states of my component are reset**?

```
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('');

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated, isSuccess, isError, message } = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const userData = {
      email,
      password,
    };
    dispatch(login(userData));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess && isAuthenticated) {
      navigate('/');
    }
  }, [isSuccess, isAuthenticated]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
    }
  }, [isError]);
```

In this example, after filling my form, when I run `handleLogin()` who has the `dispatch` line, `email` and `password` are both reset to ''. I have the same issue in every component when I'm trying to dispatch.

How to prevent this behaviour?

Here is how I'd setup my Redux Store:

app/store.tsx

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import userReducer from '../features/user/userSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    user: userReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

app/hook.tsx

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

app.js

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { isSuccess, isError } = useAppSelector((state) => state.user);
  const token = Cookies.get('service_token') || localStorage.getItem('token');

  function WithNav() {
    return (
      <>
        <NavBar isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} authLoading={isLoading} />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer />
      </>
    );
  }

  function WithoutNav() {
    return <Outlet />;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      dispatch(getUserData(token));
    } else {
      dispatch(notAuthenticated({}));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess) {
      dispatch(setUser(token));
    } else if (isError) {
      dispatch(notAuthenticated({}));
    }
  }, [isSuccess, isLoading, isError]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<WithoutNav />}>
          <Route path='connexion' element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path='inscription' element={<Register />}></Route>
          <Route path='quiz' element={<Quiz />}></Route>
          <Route path='*' element={<NotMatch />}></Route>
        </Route>
        <Route element={<WithNav />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

features/auth/authSlice.tsx

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, Slice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authService from './authService';
import { IUserDataAuth } from '../../types/Users';

// Define a type for the slice state
interface IAuthState {
  token: string | null;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
  message: string;
}

// Define the initial state using that type
const initialState: IAuthState = {
  token: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: true,
  message: '',
};

export const register = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/register',
  async (user: IUserDataAuth, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await authService.register(user);
    } catch (error: any) {
      const message =
        error?.response?.data?.message || error.message || error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/login',
  async (user: IUserDataAuth, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await authService.login(user);
    } catch (error: any) {
      const message =
        error?.response?.data?.message || error.message || error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

export const logout = createAsyncThunk('auth/logout', async () => {
  authService.logout();
});

export const authSlice: Slice<IAuthState> = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isError = false;
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.message = '';
    },
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.token = action.payload;
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
    notAuthenticated: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
    sessionExpired: (state) => {
      state.token = null;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(register.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(register.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.token = action.payload;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
      })
      .addCase(register.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload as string;
        state.token = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
      })
      .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.token = action.payload;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        // state.message = action.payload as string;
        state.message =
          'Erreur de connexion. Veuillez vérifier vos identiants.';
        state.token = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
      })
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.token = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset, setUser, sessionExpired, notAuthenticated } =
  authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using `handleLogin` as the submit handler of a `form` element and submitting a form and reloading the page, e.g. the app and all components remount with initial state. The callback should prevent the default form action, e.g. not submit the form.

Example:

```
const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated, isSuccess, isError, message } = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent submitting the form

    const userData = {
      email,
      password,
    };

    dispatch(login(userData));
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...

    <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      ...

      <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>

    ...
  );
};
```